# SOAP request going to localhost

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I'm testing a SOAP web service using Soap UI.
The WSDL location is on an external server, so I load and create a new project like this:
[image]

However, when I try to create a request, the endpoint points to localhost:
[image]

I have to manually insert the right endpoint URL for the request to work.
What could be behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the `wsdl` file in a *browser* or in a *text editor*, it will be clear that the endpoint has the same url, i.e., localhost, but not the actual one. That is the reason you are experiencing that.

This mostly happens also as developers try to use localhost while developing and it is not required/no point/does not make sense to have their *hostname* in wsdl unless it is a *public wsdl*. If QA team is using, then they will set their hostname in the endpoint, similarly for the other environments. So, you really do not have to worry about it, I believe.

In order to set the right endpoint at one place and apply for all requests( instead of changing it for each and every request), do the following:

- Go to the service interface, right click and show interface viewer.
- Click on Service Endpoints tab.
- Click on `+` button.
- Add the actual endpoint what you wanted
- Click on `Assign` button, and select `All requests and Test Requests` from dropdown and say `ok`
- Repeat the same if you have multiple `interfaces` in your project.

Save the project, and you are done.

You should be able to see the desired endpoint for all the existing test requests and even for the new one that you are going to create later.